# Name of objects containing tables in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here is an example of Google's BigQuery browser view:

[image]

What are the entities containing the tables (ie `ga_sessions_(366)` on the above example) called? Ie what are `geolite2`, `ghcn_d`, `ghcn_m`, `github_repos`, `google_analytics_sample`, etc on the above screenshot? (Red rectangle is drawn around them to make it clearer.)

(Image [source](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-query-and-calculate-google-analytics-data-in-bigquery-cab8fc4f396).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are `datasets`. Check out the Big Query UI [overview](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui).

Datasets are used to organize and control access to tables and views.